# PHP namespace error

Tags: php, codeigniter, namespaces

I have a problem with a PHP API library which is supposed to work. I am using the codeigniter framework.

I am trying to use the PHPEVECentral library from my eve_market_model. As you can see the library is composed of several files using namespaces. To use the library, i have just include the main file PHPEVECentral.

Here, you can find a screenshot of the arborescence folders.

[image: http://s21.postimg.org/byz3udi8n/arbo.png]

```
namespace PHPEveCentral;

class PHPEveCentral
{
    ...

    public function MarketStat($typeid = array())
    {
        return new \PHPEveCentral\Requests\MarketStat($typeid);
    }
}
```

So, when i call PHPEveCentral->MarketStat() function, I get a php error :

```
Class 'PHPEveCentral\Requests\MarketStat' not found in C:\wamp\www\Eve-board\application\libraries\PHPEveCentral\PHPEveCentral.php on line 68
```

When I include the PHPEveCentral\Requests\MarketStat.php file, there is not this error anymore but then i have an other error for an other file, so i have to include it too and so on.

Do I have to manually include each file of the library? I hope there is an other way because it's a bit boring.

Thanks you for your help.

**EDIT**

I extended the CodeIgniter Loader class adding a method to recursivly include all file of a folder. https://github.com/zallek/CodeIgniter/blob/master/MY_Loader.php

Using this method, I don't get any error and that's works. The only problem is an optimization problem :

The Load->file() just include the file as PHP vanilla does while Load->class() is design to instanciate only once the class (singleton). But I can't use Load->class() because there are some interfaces which do not work with this method. So maybe, I should find a way to detect if it's a Class file or an Interface file ...

Comment: Sounds like you're supposed to set up an *autoloader*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to set up is what is called auto loading. If you name your files correctly it will properly load them as needed.

There's a standard for it called PSR-0, which you can read about about at https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

You also have a sample implementation there.

Answer (score -1):

Try with codeinginter Loader class

$this->load->library('class_name', $config, 'object name')

For details

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Comment: that's what I alreay do when I say "include" (to not disturb people who don't know CodeIgniter).